# Dynamic filters and columns using command.parameters()

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm tring to create a dynamic query based on user input (textbox) so the user fills any textbox and the command adapts both the columns and `WHERE` conditionals. 
So what i've done is create arrays for both parameters and the `for` statement scans each non-null values in the conditionals array, based on it I create sql `.Parameters`, one fills columns that will be displayed and the other applies conditionals.
The problem it's obviusly that the `for` adds the wrong sintaxis for the sql `SELECT`, so instead of this:

```
SELECT [COL_N],[COL_N+1] FROM [TABLE1] WHERE [CONDITION_N] LIKE '%[VALUE]%' AND [CONDITION_N+1] = '%[VALUE]%'
```

I get this:

```
SELECT [COL_N],[COL_N+1], FROM [TABLE1] WHERE [CONDITION_N] LIKE '%[VALUE]%' AND [CONDITION_N+1] = '%[VALUE]%' AND
```

This is my code

```
var arregloParametro =  new[] { col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7 };
var arregloColumnas =   new[] { val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7 };

try
        {

            connSQL.Open();

            // PROCESO BUSCAR
            SqlCommand selProc = connSQL.CreateCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter adaptadorDatos1 = new SqlDataAdapter(selProc);

            for (int i = 0; i < arregloParametro.Length; i++)
            {
                if (arregloParametro[i] != null || arregloParametro[i] != "")
                {

                    string colQuery = arregloColumnas[i] + ", ";
                    string filPar = arregloColumnas[i] + " LIKE '" + arregloParametro[i] + "' AND ";

                    selProc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmdCol", arregloColumnas[i] + ", ");
                    selProc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmdFil", arregloColumnas[i] + " LIKE '%" + arregloParametro[i] + "%' AND ");

                    lblColFil.Text = colQuery;
                    lblColUsadas.Text = filPar;

                }
            }

            selProc.CommandText = "SELECT @cmdCol FROM tTest WHERE @cmdFil;";
            selProc.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            DataTable tablaProcRes = new DataTable();
            adaptadorDatos1.Fill(tablaProcRes);

            gridBuscarRUT.DataSource = tablaProcRes;
            gridBuscarRUT.DataBind();
            gridBuscarRUT.Visible = true;

            connSQL.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblConexion.Visible = true;
            lblConexion.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
```

I'm looking for a better approach rather than fixing this block of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

using string.join (and modifying your datastructure) i can generate the colquery and parameters in 2 lines

```
        var input = new[]{new Tuple<string,string>(col1,val1),new Tuple<string,string>(col2,val3),...};

        ....

        string colQuery = string.Join(", ", input.Where(i => i.Item1 !=  null || i.Tiem2 != null));
        string filPar = string.Join(" AND ", input.Where(i => i.Item1 !=  null || i.Tiem2 != null).Select(i => $"{i.item1} LIKE {i.item2}" ))
```

hope this helps